# grunt: make several multi language htmls from one html

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, console, gruntjs

Used `grunt` and `grunt-preprocess` to prepare my html files.

How can I make several multi language html files (each file with translation for it language)
and with tool I should use for that? previously think about `grunt-xgettext`

Comment: What do you have for translations ? What does your HTML look like ?

Comment: At this moment - nothing - I trying to select tool for this.

Now my html looks like 
    `<html>
    <title> some text at EN</title> 
    </html>`
but need gain something like this: 

    `<html>
    <title> some text at FR</title> 
    </html>`
and
    `<html>
    <title> some text at GE</title> 
    </html>`

Comment: Are you using node for generating the pages or some client framework like angular / bootstrap ?

Comment: uning node as backend, grunt as build tool and marionette as client js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found 2 nice `grunt` plugins: `grunt-text-replace` and `grunt.template`.
Just used second one and load `data` section from external json file:

```
      template: {
        'process-en-html': {
            'options': {
                'data': grunt.file.readJSON('translates/en.json'),
            },
            'files': {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
```

for each language use common html config and its own json file